# Building a tester for 5VDC 2A power adapters

Tags: led

I am looking to built a tester for 5V 2A power adapters. I want to plug in the power adapter output lead and check for proper power output.

The wall plug outputs 5VDC at 2 amps. I also want to have a single LED to tell whether it has power or not.

Comment: I was going to edit your question but got a little confused with the title. It doesn't seem to match the question (which in turn is clear enough by itself, disregarding the title)

Comment: So, what does 3.3VDC has to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic tester:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0SuL8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 should be something in the visible spectrum.

If you need to know the exact voltage then get a voltmeter module from e.g. eBay. If you need to know if it can output all 2A then you'll need to get a dummy load.

Comment: The dummy load could be two 5R 10W resistors in parallel with proper heatsinks, right?

Comment: Sure, that would work. Or you could go for something more extravagant like the [Re:load 2](https://www.tindie.com/products/arachnidlabs/reload-the-simple-robust-affordable-dummy-load/)

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with Ohm's Law?

The max current for 5mm diameter is 20mA.

> {They act like low voltage zener diodes. }

- deep Red  1.8V (GaP) approx,
- Amber, Yellow , Red (AlInGaAs) ~2.0-2.4V approx.
- Blue , or White 3.0 to 3.6V approx
- Green 3.6-3.8V approx
- Flat bar on schematic= "cathode" (-) has a flat edge on body.
- choose current limiting resistor ,

for example deep Red (5-1.8V=3.2)
- 20mA max, = bright , ~2mA min   if you like dim.  Lets pick 10mA

So voltage drop on resistor controls current

3.2V/0.01A= 320 ohms, so nearest value = 330
[image]